# php domDocument variables

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have the following code at the moment:

```
$ip = '195.72.186.157';

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML(file_get_contents('http://www.geoffmeierhans.com/services/geo-locator/locate/?ip='.$ip.'&output=xml'));

foreach($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('city') as $link) {
    $links = array('text' => $link->nodeValue);
} 
$city = $links['text'];
echo $city;
```

Is there a better way to get the city variable? Since there is only one tag called city a loop isn't really needed but I can't get it to work any other way

Comment: *(tipp)* `DOMDocument::load` can load remote documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use the `length` parameter to [`DomNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) (what's returned by the `getElementsByTagName` call.

If you want only the first result:

```
$nodes = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('city');
if ($nodes->length > 0) {
    $city = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
} else {
    $city = '';  // There is no city element
}
```